# My code works on its own, but when I put it into a class, it breaks

Tags: java, class, processing, keypress, keyrelease

I have been making this alien game where you have to control the alien on a screen using "wasd", but when I put my code into a class, the class does not read `Alien.KeyReleased` in the set up, and I have no idea why

```
Alien Alien;

void setup(){
  
  size (950, 650);
  background(10,10,20);
  Alien = new Alien(90, 150, 200, 200);
}

void draw() {
  noStroke();
  background(10,10,25);

  Alien.drawAlien();
  Alien.moveAlien();
  Alien.checkForedge();
  Alien.keyReleased();
  Alien.keyPressed();
}
```

```
class Alien {
  
int alienSpeed = 5;
boolean moveUp;
boolean moveDown;
boolean moveLeft;
boolean moveRight;

int boundboxXLoc = 325;
int boundboxYLoc = 325;
int boundboxWidth = 90;
int boundboxHeight = 150;

//body
int BodyXLoc;
int BodyYLoc;
int BodyWidth;
int BodyHeight;

//spot1 
int spot1XLoc ;
int spot1YLoc ;
int spot1Width;
int spot1Height;

//spot2 
int spot2XLoc ;
int spot2YLoc ;
int spot2Width;
int spot2Height;

//spot23
int spot3XLoc ;
int spot3YLoc ;
int spot3Width;
int spot3Height;

//Generate random colours
int Red = (int) random(200);
int Blue = (int) random(200);
int Green = (int) random(200);
int Opacity = 255;

//Generate spot1 Loc, mid
int spot1LocX = (int) random(-13,8);

//Generate spot2Loc, small
int spot2LocX = (int) random(-4,27);

//Generate spot3 Loc, big
int spot3LocX = (int) random(-2,20);

//arms 
int armsXLoc ;
int armsYLoc ;
int armsWidth;
int armsHeight;

//head
int HeadXLoc;
int HeadYLoc; 
int HeadWidth;
int HeadHeight;

//mouth
int mouthXLoc;
int mouthYLoc;
int mouthWidth;
int mouthHeight;

//eyestalk
int eyestalkXLoc;
int eyestalkYLoc;
int eyestalkWidth;
int eyestalkHeight;

//eyestalk1
int eyestalk1XLoc;
int eyestalk1YLoc;
int eyestalk1Width;
int eyestalk1Height;

//eyestalk2
int eyestalk2XLoc;
int eyestalk2YLoc;
int eyestalk2Width;
int eyestalk2Height;

//eyestalk3
int eyestalk3XLoc;
int eyestalk3YLoc;
int eyestalk3Width;
int eyestalk3Height;

//eyestalk4
int eyestalk4XLoc;
int eyestalk4YLoc;
int eyestalk4Width;
int eyestalk4Height;

//eyestalk5
int eyestalk5XLoc;
int eyestalk5YLoc;
int eyestalk5Width;
int eyestalk5Height;

//eyestalk6
int eyestalk6XLoc;
int eyestalk6YLoc;
int eyestalk6Width;
int eyestalk6Height;

///eyestalk7
int eyestalk7XLoc;
int eyestalk7YLoc;
int eyestalk7Width;
int eyestalk7Height;

//ship
int shipXLoc;
int shipYLoc;
int shipWidth = 180;
int shipHeight = 75;

//ship1
int ship1XLoc;
int ship1YLoc;
int ship1Width = 100;
int ship1Height = 30;
  
  
  
  Alien (int bW, int bH, int xL, int yL) {
   
    boundboxWidth = bW;
    boundboxHeight = bH;
    boundboxXLoc = xL;
    boundboxYLoc = yL;

  } 
  
  
  // draw the boundary box
    void drawAlien() {
    fill (100,0,0,0);
    ellipse(boundboxXLoc, boundboxYLoc, boundboxWidth, boundboxHeight);

 // draw the Body
     fill (Red,Green,Blue,Opacity);
     ellipse(BodyXLoc, BodyYLoc, BodyWidth, BodyHeight);
     BodyXLoc = boundboxXLoc;
     BodyYLoc = boundboxYLoc + (boundboxHeight/8);
     BodyWidth = boundboxWidth / (175/75) ;
     BodyHeight = boundboxHeight / (250/100); 
     

 // draw the head
    fill (Red,Green,Blue,Opacity);
    ellipse(HeadXLoc, HeadYLoc, HeadWidth, HeadHeight); 
    HeadXLoc = boundboxXLoc;
    HeadYLoc = boundboxYLoc - (boundboxHeight/5);
    HeadWidth = boundboxWidth / (175/70);
    HeadHeight = boundboxHeight / (250/56); 
  
 // draw the right eye stalk
    fill (Red,Green,Blue,Opacity);
    rect(eyestalkXLoc, eyestalkYLoc, eyestalkWidth, eyestalkHeight);
    eyestalkXLoc = boundboxXLoc + (boundboxWidth/17);
    eyestalkYLoc = boundboxYLoc - (boundboxHeight/2)+15;
    eyestalkWidth = boundboxWidth / (175/20) - 1;
    eyestalkHeight = boundboxHeight / (250/50); 
 
 // draw the left eye stalk
    fill (Red,Green,Blue,Opacity);
    rect(eyestalk1XLoc, eyestalk1YLoc, eyestalk1Width, eyestalk1Height);
    eyestalk1XLoc = boundboxXLoc -(boundboxWidth/6);
    eyestalk1YLoc = boundboxYLoc - (boundboxHeight/2)+15;
    eyestalk1Width = boundboxWidth / (175/20) - 1;
    eyestalk1Height = boundboxHeight / (250/50);
 
 // the white part of the eye, right  
    fill (255,255,255);
    ellipse(eyestalk2XLoc, eyestalk2YLoc, eyestalk2Width, eyestalk2Height);
    eyestalk2XLoc = boundboxXLoc + boundboxWidth / (175/20);
    eyestalk2YLoc = boundboxYLoc - boundboxHeight / (240/75);
    eyestalk2Width = boundboxWidth / (175/10);
    eyestalk2Height = boundboxHeight / (250/30);
 
 // the white part of the eye, left  
    fill (255,255,255);
    ellipse(eyestalk3XLoc, eyestalk3YLoc, eyestalk3Width, eyestalk3Height);
    eyestalk3XLoc = boundboxXLoc - boundboxWidth / (175/20);
    eyestalk3YLoc = boundboxYLoc - boundboxHeight / (240/75);
    eyestalk3Width = boundboxWidth / (175/10);
    eyestalk3Height = boundboxHeight / (250/30);
    
 // the right pupil
    fill (0,0,0);
    ellipse(eyestalk4XLoc, eyestalk4YLoc, eyestalk4Width, eyestalk4Height);
    eyestalk4XLoc = boundboxXLoc + boundboxWidth / (175/20);
    eyestalk4YLoc = boundboxYLoc - boundboxHeight / (240/75);
    eyestalk4Width = boundboxWidth / (175/5);
    eyestalk4Height = boundboxHeight / (250/15);
    
 // the left pupil
    fill (0,0,0);
    ellipse(eyestalk5XLoc, eyestalk5YLoc, eyestalk5Width, eyestalk5Height);
    eyestalk5XLoc = boundboxXLoc - boundboxWidth / (175/20);
    eyestalk5YLoc = boundboxYLoc - boundboxHeight / (240/75);
    eyestalk5Width = boundboxWidth / (175/5);
    eyestalk5Height = boundboxHeight / (250/15);
    
 // the top part of the eye stalk, right
    fill (Red,Green,Blue,Opacity);
    ellipse(eyestalk6XLoc, eyestalk6YLoc, eyestalk6Width, eyestalk6Height);
    eyestalk6XLoc = boundboxXLoc + boundboxWidth / (175/19);
    eyestalk6YLoc = eyestalkYLoc;
    eyestalk6Width = boundboxWidth / (175/20);
    eyestalk6Height = boundboxHeight / (250/20);
    
 // the top part of the eye stalk, left
    fill (Red,Green,Blue,Opacity);
    ellipse(eyestalk7XLoc, eyestalk7YLoc, eyestalk7Width, eyestalk7Height);
    eyestalk7XLoc = boundboxXLoc - boundboxWidth / (175/19);
    eyestalk7YLoc = eyestalkYLoc;
    eyestalk7Width = boundboxWidth / (175/20);
    eyestalk7Height = boundboxHeight / (250/20);
   
 // The mouth
   fill (50,50,50);
   ellipse(mouthXLoc, mouthYLoc, mouthWidth, mouthHeight);
   mouthXLoc = boundboxXLoc;
   mouthYLoc = boundboxYLoc - boundboxHeight/6;
   mouthWidth = boundboxWidth / (175/40);
   mouthHeight = boundboxHeight / (250/10);

 // the arms
   fill (Red,Green,Blue,Opacity);
   ellipse(armsXLoc, armsYLoc, armsWidth, armsHeight);
   armsXLoc = BodyXLoc; 
   armsYLoc = BodyYLoc-10;
   armsWidth = boundboxWidth ;
   armsHeight = boundboxHeight / (250/15);
   
 //spot1
   fill ((Red-40),(Green-40),(Blue-40),Opacity);
   ellipse(spot1XLoc, spot1YLoc, spot1Width, spot1Height);
   spot1XLoc = boundboxXLoc + spot1LocX + (boundboxWidth/20);
   spot1YLoc = boundboxYLoc + (boundboxHeight/50);
   spot1Width = boundboxWidth / (175/30) ;
   spot1Height = boundboxHeight / (250/15); 
     
  //spot2
   fill ((Red-40),(Green-40),(Blue-40),Opacity);
   ellipse(spot2XLoc, spot2YLoc, spot2Width, spot2Height);
   spot2XLoc = boundboxXLoc + spot2LocX - (boundboxWidth / 10);
   spot2YLoc = boundboxYLoc  - (boundboxHeight/20);
   spot2Width = boundboxWidth / (175/15) ;
   spot2Height = boundboxHeight / (250/13); 
     
  //spot3
   fill ((Red-40),(Green-40),(Blue-40),Opacity);
   ellipse(spot3XLoc, spot3YLoc, spot3Width, spot3Height);
   spot3XLoc = boundboxXLoc + spot3LocX - (boundboxWidth / 10);
   spot3YLoc = boundboxYLoc + (boundboxHeight/10);
   spot3Width = boundboxWidth / (175/50) ;
   spot3Height = boundboxHeight / (250/23); 

 // the ship
   fill (100,100,100);
   ellipse(shipXLoc, shipYLoc, shipWidth, shipHeight);
   shipXLoc = BodyXLoc; 
   shipYLoc = (BodyYLoc + (boundboxHeight/5));
   shipWidth = boundboxWidth;
   shipHeight = boundboxHeight / (250/75);

 // the bottom of the ship
    fill (150,170,200);
    ellipse(ship1XLoc, ship1YLoc, ship1Width, ship1Height);
    ship1XLoc = BodyXLoc; 
    ship1YLoc = (shipYLoc + (shipHeight/3));
    ship1Width = boundboxWidth / (250/100);
    ship1Height = boundboxHeight / (250/30);
 
}
  
  void moveAlien() {
  if (moveUp) {
    boundboxYLoc -= alienSpeed;
  }
  if (moveRight) {
    if (moveUp) {
      boundboxXLoc += (int) (alienSpeed * Math.sqrt(2) / 2);
      boundboxYLoc -= (int) (alienSpeed * Math.sqrt(2) / 2);
    } else {
      boundboxXLoc += alienSpeed;
    }
  }
  if (moveDown) {
    boundboxYLoc += alienSpeed;
  }
  if (moveLeft) {
    if (moveDown) {
      boundboxXLoc -= (int) (alienSpeed * Math.sqrt(2) / 2);
      boundboxYLoc += (int) (alienSpeed * Math.sqrt(2) / 2);
    } else {
      boundboxXLoc -= alienSpeed;
    }
 }
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (key == 'w') {
    moveUp = false;
  }
  if (key == 'a') {
    moveLeft = false;
  }
  if (key == 's') {
    moveDown = false;
  }
  if (key == 'd') {
    moveRight = false;
  }
}


void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'w') {
    moveUp = true;
  }
  if (key == 's') {
    moveDown = true;
  }
  if (key == 'a') {
    moveLeft = true;
  }
  if (key == 'd') {
    moveRight = true;
  }
}

void checkForedge() {
  
// right wall
  if(boundboxXLoc >= 990) {
      boundboxXLoc = boundboxXLoc -1050;

  }  
// left wall
    if(boundboxXLoc <= -50) {
      boundboxXLoc = boundboxXLoc + 1050;

    }
// bottom wall
  if(boundboxYLoc <= -70) {
      boundboxYLoc = boundboxYLoc + 780;

  }  
// top wall
    if(boundboxYLoc >= 700) {
      boundboxYLoc = boundboxYLoc - 780; 
    
  }
}
  
}//end class
```

I tried moving about the position of `ALien.KeyPressed` and `Alien.KeyReleased` hoping it would help it read it, but thats had no affect

Comment: That is _way_ too many `int` properties. All of them are x/y/w/h sets: make _that_ a class so that instead of _sixty eight individual ints_ you at least have only 17 things, but really, wrap those in some sensible classes too, like a `body` and a `ship` and `spots` or something. What you're showing is... not good.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Processing, your `init` and `draw` methods, and all the other code in your sketch is inserted into a new class which is generated by Processing. This class extends `PApplet`.

You can see the Javadoc here: https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html

That parent class is where methods like `keyPressed` are declared. Processing will call your implementation of those methods, but only on the `PApplet` subclass it has created.

When you move your code to a class which doesn't extend `PApplet`, those methods are no longer called by the framework.

You can keep all your code in your own class while still having the Processing framework call those methods by delegating them to your Alien instance:

```
// these methods are in your sketch, not your Alien class
void keyReleased() {
  alien.keyReleased();
}

void keyPressed() {
  alien.keyPressed();
}
```

You don't need to change your `Alien` implementation.

(I've renamed your field `Alien` to `alien` -- variable names should not start with capital letters)

Comment: thank you very much @tgdavies, i've never coded java before and i had no idea what to do, i appreciate the help 